# Summer 16 Lightning components in Visualforce pages throw Lightning Out Error

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, summer-16

Did anyone else notice this with Summer 16 instances?
I have a Visualforce page that contains a lightning component. This works fine in production.

In a sandbox on Summer 16, I get a 500 Server error though. This is the error from console:

```
lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1463003607149:112 GET https://mydomain--dev--c.cs41.visual.force.com/c/POApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT 500 (Server Error)
$Lightning._delegate.use @ lightning.out.delegate.js?v=1463003607149:112
script.onload @ lightning.out.js?v=2:37
```

Comment: The issue has been reported and is being investigated. I do not have any additional details at this time.

Comment: I still see this issue in sandbox. Our production instance will be in Summer 16 tomorrow. Will we see this in production also?

Comment: Do you have a case open on this already? can you provide more details such as the contents of the 500 server error (error ID or error message, etc - might be visible in the network tab in Chrome dev tools). I am raising this again with the team  to see what is going on but it would be helpful to have a case to be able to make sure it does not fall through the cracks again.

Comment: The network tab shows this message: An internal server error has occurred.
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact <a href="https://help.salesforce.com/apex/hthome">Salesforce Support</a>. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. 
Error ID: 297759719-11207 (-418637590)

Comment: Also opened a case with Salesforce. Case #  13994897

Comment: Did you get this issue solved, or was it classified as a bug, or what? I'm having a similar issue, but only with a certain group of users.

Comment: Nope, I think this stopped happening after the release. We haven't seen this again. They refused to give a detailed answer since we didn't have premier support at the time.